# How to create a custom shape that varies in width

Tags: css

In this mockup I have created, I am trying to create a custom arrow shape below each button whenever the mouse hovers over a button on the main navigation. However, the width will vary for each button and I need it to look the same. How would I accomplish this in CSS?
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvlIx.png) to see what I am trying to accomplish under 'I'm New' link.

So far, this is what I have in style.css:

```
.main_nav_inside {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -130px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main_nav_inside ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
}

.main_nav_inside ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

.main_nav_inside ul li a {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 130px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.main_nav_inside ul li a:hover {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2F2F2F;
}

.main_nav_inside ul li a:hover:before {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: calc(2% + 30px);
  background-color: #000000;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: inherit;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: 0;
  top: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000000;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 15deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
.main_nav_inside ul li a:hover:after {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: calc(10% / 2);
  background-color: #000000;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: inherit;
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-right: 0;
  top: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000000;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -15deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Here is the HTML for this page as well:

```
<header id="header_inside">
      <div class="main_logo_white"><a href="{{ siteUrl }}"><img src="{{ siteUrl }}/images/ssumc_logo_white.png"></a></div>

  {% set parents = craft.entries.section('menu').level(1).limit(5) %}
  <nav class="main_nav_inside">
      <ul>
        {% nav parent in parents %}
        <li>
          {{ parent.getLink() }}
            {% ifchildren %}
              <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li>{% children %}</li>
              </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
          {% endnav %}
      </ul>

  </nav>
</header>
```

This website is being built using Craft CMS..not that this matters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Post your HTML as well.

Comment: Also, can you show the rest of your CSS, including how you have .main_nav_inside defined? Thanks!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you want the arrow to vary in width, do you want to keep the angle the same (e.g. wider element means the tip of the arrow will be further down), or you want to keep the height of the arrow constant (e.g. wider element means a shallower arrow angle)?

Comment: Terry, yes. it would basically stay at the same height. Roughly 30px.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions? I possibly was thinking this should be done in jQuery to work with the CSS for this header in particular.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the shape using border-top, border-left and border-right. But the bottom tip seems to stay flat and doesn't have a point to it. No matter what numbers you adjust in the border width of top, left or right the tip will stay flat.

```
.main_nav_inside ul li a:hover:after {
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 20px solid #000000;
    border-left: 50px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 50px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```